# Is it possible to lock in a screen resolution in XP

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, display-settings

I have an XP box connected to a KVM switch, every time the computer boots, the screen resolution gets reset to the switches maximum resolution which is different than the screens native resolution.  I would like to set the display resolution and lock it so it can't change.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your KVM does not correctly implement [Display Data Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) or has a fault or needs some configuration?

> Some KVM switches (keyboard-video-mouse) and video extenders handle DDC traffic incorrectly, making it necessary to disable monitor plug and play features in the operating system, and maybe even physically remove pin 12 from the analog VGA cables that connects such device to multiple PCs.
>
> [...]
>
> The Display Resolution control panel applet allows the user to disable this driver's Plug and Play features and manually select any resolution or refresh rate supported by the video card.

Comment: Could be since it was only $13 with all cables (went cheap to see if I would even like the solution which I now love).  Anyone know if disable PnP?  Should be an XP thing, or if it would have to be driver related? In this case nVidia.  Absent that I'll just switch it before booting which also works fine.